# Kerning of usernames

Tags: discussion

The kerning of usernames isn't that good for me. It's almost keming. As a result, I almost misspelt the username, which meant the user wouldn't have received a reply.

Is this a problem for most users, or do I just need to get glasses?

> [image: Screenshot]
>
> Screenshot of [comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/what-does-the-term-prenominally-mean/21383#comment46889_21381)

If we're choosing a specific font because it needs to support non-romaji characters, that's fine.

Comment: The Furigana engine does make Japanese+fullwidth Latin text display in a Japanese font ([details](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=18968558#18968558)), but halfwidth Latin etc in usernames (which is what is used in this case) should be displayed using the `body` font which is AFAIK the same for all beta sites: `"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same font used on all beta sites (cf. [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/588/#comment1367_588), [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7249/#comment9040_7249), [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/#comment4657_2524)). It kerns badly for me, too.

Comment: Oh no, I find I actually misspelled their name...